# Angular How to use Date Pipe with a condition

Tags: angular, pipe

Is there a way to add a condition to the Date Pipe ? Currently the code will work if there are dates to be displayed but if the array is empty, I set futureDateProjects.viewValue = "No Futures Dates" in my code. However, in the current code below, it will not display 'No Future Dates' in the dropdown if there are not no dates to be displayed.

```
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="project?.Attributes.test" name="test">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let futureProject of futureDateProjects" [value]="futureProject.value">
          {{futureProject.viewValue | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
        </mat-option>
```

Test.Component.ts

```
   if (this.futureEffDate.length === 0) {
        this.futureDateProjects.push({ value: this.test, viewValue: 'No Future Dates' });
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to put a condition on the pipe. I'd use a *ngIf like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="test" name="test">
  <option *ngIf="futureDateProjects.length===0" value="">No Future Date</option>
  <option *ngFor="let futureProject of futureDateProjects" [value]="futureProject.value">
          {{futureProject.viewValue | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
  </option>
</select>
```

If it's functionality you'll be using a lot, create your own pipe and wrap this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a different templates inside option. Send you a simplified version, but the idea is next:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let futureProject of futureDateProjects" [value]="futureProject.value">
<span *ngIf="futureProject.viewValue !== 'No Future Dates'">{{futureProject.viewValue | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="futureProject.viewValue === 'No Future Dates'">{{futureProject.viewValue}}</span>
            </mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify a condition in TS file. Remove the length condition when there is no data in the array. Just add this element in your html:

```
<mat-option *ngIf="!futureDateProjects.length">
  No Future Dates
  </mat-option>
```

Your final select will have:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="project?.Attributes.test" name="test">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let futureProject of futureDateProjects" 
            [value]="futureProject.value">
          {{futureProject.viewValue | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
   </mat-option>

   <mat-option *ngIf="!futureDateProjects.length">
      No Future Dates
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I hope this resolves your issue! Do Upvote!